# Шахматы на js

Tags: javascript

www.subjay.ru

делаю шахматы на js, справа выводятся лог,и появляется вертикальная полоса прокрутки,вот как сделать чтобы она всегда находилась внизу,ато приходится ее постоянно вниз мотать?

Comment: Не пробовал, но возможно [это][1]

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так:

```
document.forms.FF.b.scrollTop = document.forms.FF.b.scrollHeight;
```

ЗЫ это у вас обфускатор так работает или вы так и пишите? (код, я так понимаю ваш)

Comment: чет не получается(

Comment: @Руслан Сабанов, код не ваш, ясно. Измените функцию Df так:

    function Df(x) {
 d.FF.b.value += '\n ' + x;
        d.FF.b.scrollTop = d.FF.b.scrollHeight;
    }

Answer (score -1):

```
var maxScrollTop = $('textarea').prop('scrollHeight');
var innerHeight = $('textarea').innerHeight();
$('textarea').scrollTop(maxScrollTop - innerHeight);
```

И поставить это всё на событие, когда появляется новая запись в textarea, ну или что-то в этом духе. Сами разберётесь. 
Ответ на этот вопрос легко находится в гугле, кстати. На английском.